# Compare execution of same ssis package

Tags: ssis

I'm a complete novice on how to use SSIS.

My problem is that the update time of our data warehouse is not stable and the same package can run in either 25 minutes or 4 hours.

I've used this code:

```
declare @fromDate datetime,  @toDate datetime
select @fromDate = '2018-11-29 00:00:00'
select @toDate = '2018-11-30 00:00:00'

SELECT  event_message_id
,[MESSAGE]
, message_time
,package_name
,event_name,message_source_name
,package_path
,execution_path
,message_type
,message_source_type
FROM   (
   SELECT  em.*
   FROM    SSISDB.catalog.event_messages em
WHERE   package_name = 'TransformFinancialOrderDetail.dtsx' and message_time between @fromDate and @toDate
ORDER BY message_time DESC
```

To determine where in the execute things are not working. I've identified these two events

[image]

between which there is a huge time spam. I would like to be able to find out what is happening between these two steps. My only problem is that I do not know how to proceed. I do not expect anybody to do my job, but I would appreciate guidance into which direction i should search.

Comment: There's probably not enough information here to provide an authoritative answer. Does this one package solve the entirety of your data warehouse loading or are there multiple packages? Did the package designers follow good practices and create explicit instrumentation tables for the loads (package 1 ran: 100 insert, 20 updates, 1 delete, 100000 from source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a better idea of what may be causing the inconsistencies in the run time, try using the `catalog.execution_component_phases` system DMV to get more granularity.  This will provide the time each task spent within each phase (i.e. ProcessInput, PrimeOutput, etc.) which should allow you to see where the slowdown is occurring and help determine the source of this.  An important thing to note, to use this DMV the logging will need to be enabled and set to either the **Performance** or **Verbose** level.  To use this DMV will also require membership to either the `ssis_admin` database role or `sysadmin` server role, however having read permission of the execution of this package will also allow for viewing the results.

Comment: Thank you. I'll follow this path to find the reason. Appreciated.